# ２分木探索のプログラムで segmentation fault が発生する場合がある

Tags: c

このプログラムを実行したときに挿入してない値を探索した場合、segmentation faultが出ます。原因はなんでしょうか？

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// キー比較関数の定義
#define keycmp(x, y)  ((x)-(y))

// KEY 型を定義（正体は int 型）
typedef int KEY;

// NODE型の構造体定義
typedef struct node {
    struct    node    *left, *right;  // 左右部分木へのポインタ
    KEY       key;                    // データ部
} NODE;

// 各種関数のプロトタイプ宣言
void init(void);
NODE *insert( NODE node );
int delete(KEY key);

void clear(void);
void dispsub(NODE *p);
void disp(int n);

// 探索関数のプロトタイプ宣言
NODE *search( KEY key);

// ツリーのルートを保持するポインタ変数の宣言
NODE    *root;

// 使用可能なノードの最大数を定数として宣言
#define     N   31

// 表確認関数で使用する変数の宣言
int         exist[N+1];
NODE        x[N+1];

//------------------------------
//    メイン関数（対話的な動作確認用）
//------------------------------
int    main(void)
{
    char    buff[8];
    int        succeeded;
    KEY        key;
    NODE    node, *resNode;
    
    // 木の初期化
    init();
    
    // メニューループ
    while( 1 ){
        
        // メニュー表示と選択
        printf("Sn: 探索，In: 挿入，Dn: 削除, Q: 終了 ? ");
        gets(buff);
        key = atoi(&buff[1]);
        
        // メニュー形式による処理分岐
        switch( buff[0] ){
                
                // (1) 探索の場合
            case 'S':    case 's':
                
                // 探索関数を呼ぶ
                resNode = search(key);
                
                // 結果を表示する
                if( resNode != NULL )
                    printf("\nキー %d を見つけました．\n", resNode->key);
                else
                    printf("\nキー %d は見つかりません．\n", resNode->key);
                break;
                
                //(2) 挿入の場合
            case 'I':    case 'i' :
                
                // 挿入関数を呼ぶ
                node.key = key;
                resNode = insert( node );
                
                // 結果を表示する
                if( resNode != NULL )
                    printf("キー %d を挿入しました．\n", key);
                else
                    printf("キー %d は挿入済みです．\n", key);
                break;
                
                //(3) 削除の場合
            case 'D':    case 'd':
                
                // 削除関数を呼ぶ
                succeeded = delete( key );
                
                // 結果を表示する
                if( succeeded )
                    printf("キー %d を削除しました．\n", key);
                else
                    printf("キー %d を削除できません．\n", key);
                break;

                //(4) 終了の場合
            case 'Q':    case 'q':
                return 0;
                
                // その他の入力を無視する
                
        }
        // ２分探索木を表示する
        clear();
        dispsub(root);
        disp(N);
    }
    
    return 0;
}

//------------------------------
//  初期化関数
//------------------------------
void init(void)
{
    root = NULL;
}

//------------------------------
//  挿入関数
//------------------------------
NODE *insert( NODE node )
{
    NODE    **pp, *pos;
    int        res;
    
    pp = &root;
    
    while( *pp != NULL ) {
        res = keycmp( node.key, (*pp)->key );
        if( res == 0 )        return NULL;
        else    if( res < 0 )    pp = &(*pp)->left;
        else    pp = &(*pp)->right;
    }
    
    /* ノード型のメモリを確保する（確保できなければ終了する） */
    if( (pos = malloc(sizeof(NODE))) == NULL )    exit(1);
    
    *pos = node;
    pos->left = pos->right = NULL;
    *pp = pos;
    return    pos;
}

//------------------------------
//  削除関数
//------------------------------
int delete(KEY key)
{
    NODE    **pp, **qq, *q, *r;
    int        res;
    
    pp = &root;
    
    while( *pp != NULL){
        
        res = keycmp( key, (*pp)->key );
        
        if( res == 0 ){
            q = *pp;
            if( q->left == NULL ){
                *pp = q->right;
                free(q);
            } else if( q->right == NULL ){
                *pp = q->left;
                free(q);
            } else {
                qq = &q->left;
                while( (*qq)->right != NULL )    qq = &(*qq)->right;
                q->key = (*qq)->key;
                r = *qq;
                *qq = (*qq)->left;
                free(r);
            }
            return    1;
            
        } else    if( res < 0 )    pp = &(*pp)->left;
        else            pp = &(*pp)->right;
    }
    return    0;
}

//====================================
//  これ以降は動作結果の確認用の関数群
//====================================

//------------------------------
//  関数 dispsub 用の補助関数
//------------------------------
void clear(void)
{
    int    i;
    for( i=1; i<=N; i++)
        exist[i] = 0;
}

//------------------------------
//  関数 disp 用の補助関数
// ------------------------------
void dispsub(NODE *p)
{
    static    int    number = 1 ;
    
    if( p == NULL )        return;
    if( number > N )     return;
    
    exist[number] = 1;
    x[number].key = p->key;
    number *= 2;
    dispsub(p->left);
    number++;
    dispsub(p->right);
    number /= 2;
}

//------------------------------
//  表示関数
// ------------------------------
void disp(int n)
{
    int    i, k, count, margin, padding;
    k = 1;    i = 1;    margin = 8;
    
    while( margin <= n )    margin*=2;
    
    while( i<=n ){
        if( i==k ){
            count = margin;
            padding = margin*2 - 2;
            k *= 2;
            margin /= 2;
            putchar('\n');
        } else
            count = padding >= 0 ? padding : 0;
        
        while( count-- )    putchar(' ');
        
        if( exist[i] )    printf("%2d", x[i].key);
        else    printf("--");
        i++;
    }
    putchar('\n');
}

//====================================
//    ２分木の探索関数
//====================================

NODE *search( KEY key)
{
    NODE *v;
    v=root; //rootにより初期位置を格納
    int res;
    res = keycmp( key, v->key ); //keyを比較
    while(v!=NULL){
        if(res==0){ //渡された値と一致している場合
            return(v);
        }
        if(res>0){ //渡された値より大きい場合
            printf("%d ",v->key);//探索経過表示
            v=v->right;

        }
        else{ //渡された値より小さい場合
            printf("%d ",v->key);//探索経過表示
            v=v->left;
        }
    }
    free(v);
    return NULL; //vが当てはまらない場合NULLを返す
}
```

実行例

```
Sn: 探索，In: 挿入，Dn: 削除, Q: 終了 ? i56
キー 56 を挿入しました．

                                56
                --                              --
        --              --              --              --
    --      --      --      --      --      --      --      --
  --  --  --  --  --  --  --  --  --  --  --  --  --  --  --  --
Sn: 探索，In: 挿入，Dn: 削除, Q: 終了 ? i32
キー 32 を挿入しました．

                                56
                32                              --
        --              --              --              --
    --      --      --      --      --      --      --      --
  --  --  --  --  --  --  --  --  --  --  --  --  --  --  --  --
Sn: 探索，In: 挿入，Dn: 削除, Q: 終了 ? s22
zsh: segmentation fault
```

Comment: 問題を発生させる入力操作の例も提示すると、より助言や回答が出やすいと思われます。

Comment: ありがとうございます。実行例を追加してみます。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

以下の部分で発生していますね。

```
        case 'S':    case 's':
            
            // 探索関数を呼ぶ
            resNode = search(key);
            
            // 結果を表示する
            if( resNode != NULL )
                printf("\nキー %d を見つけました．\n", resNode->key);
            else
                printf("\nキー %d は見つかりません．\n", resNode->key);//-->この行
            break;
```

`if( resNode != NULL )`の`else`の部分であるので、`resNode`は`NULL`なのに`resNode->key`にアクセスしているために発生しています。

対処は以下のように`resNode->`の部分は削って`key`だけにすることでしょう。

```
printf("\nキー %d は見つかりません．\n", key);
```